# Fastest way to get a part of a disk file into a particular (pre-allocated) memory address Windows/C++?

Tags: c++, windows, file, native

Howdo.

I'm working in native Windows. That said I'm looking to write a function whose prototype is something like:

```
void getData(uint8_t* p, std::string const& fn, size_t off, 
    size_t s, boost::function<void()> const& F);
```

So I've a chunk of memory, preallocated on the heap (with new). I have a file on disk. I'd like to specify a pointer into my chunk of memory ("p"), a filename ("fn") and offset therein ("off"), a size ("s") and a callback ("F"). I'd like the subroutine to eventually call "F" when my memory "p" has been populated with "s" bytes from the file "fn" at offset "off". I will guarantee "p", "s" and "off" are aligned to some predefined power of 2, but I'd like no copying that can possibly be avoided to occur. Ideally, it would DMA the data from the disk to my location directly.

I've looked into memory-mapping the file, but that would require copying the data from the mapped area into my "p". Is there no faster way of doing it?

Comment: I'd use better parameter names than p, fn, s and F!

Comment: Hmm... the whole purpose of memory mapped files is exactly not to copy anything, but rather to *map*. Maybe you should take a deeper look into this. This is a very powerful feature of Windows, available from the very first version of Windows NT.

Comment: @Simon: depends. Sometimes you need to parse/reformat the data to work with it. MMapping plus copying will *still* be magnitudes faster than regular file access for large files.

Comment: @Konrad: yea, see what you mean. I was referring to the getData function above, where I see Memory Map Files fit perfectly :)

Comment: @Simon: I don't need to reformat or parse the data. If I mmap + memcpy, Windows will inevitably stream the disk file into RAM (once a page fault occurs during memcpy if not before), and then the memcpy will copy those bytes to within my chunk of memory ('p'). I don't want to do more work (i.e. copying) than necessary; so the question can be rephrased as "Is this really the fastest way to get a big file off disk and into *my* *preallocated* memory?"

Comment: @user321091 - I think MMF would be ok if you also want to copy the bytes. However, you just added one very important information to your question. You said "big file". Now the story can really be different. It depends how big, how is the machine (RAM, 32/64-bit, etc.). See this link for a discussion about big MMF: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/khen1234/archive/2006/01/30/519483.aspx (and the comments are worth reading too)

Answer (score 4):

Why not just use memory mapping with [MapViewOfFileEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa366763%28v=VS.85%29.aspx)?

You can use `p` as the `lpBaseAddress` parameter to map the file wherever you want to in your process's address space.

Comment: Exactly. Plus I'd add that `boost::signal` doesn't comply with "fastest way". Actually it's awful from the performance point of view

Comment: I don' think that's going to work.  From the documentation: "No other memory allocation can take place in the region that is used for mapping, including the use of the VirtualAlloc or VirtualAllocEx function to reserve memory."  I just tested this and MapViewOfFileEx() fails with ERROR_INVALID_ADDRESS.  If you free the memory and then try to map it again it will succeed.

Comment: @Luke: Indeed. The pointer is a hint; nothing more. In my case, it's obviously already allocated so there's no chance of windows mapping it.